# conditional ng-required not working for textarea in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html

ng-required not working with condition. Error message not display if ng-required condition is true. please give me solution

```
  <form name="selfApprForm" novalidate ng-submit="SubmitAppraisal()">
       <div class="form-group">
             <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="comments" 
               placeholder="Comment..." style=" height: 80px;" ng- 
               model="appList.Comments" ng-required="(appList.Rating>3) ? true : 
               false"> 
            </textarea>
              <!-- validation -->                          
            <div ng-class="{'has-error' : (selfApprForm.comments.$dirty || 
                 selfApprForm.comments.$touched) && 
                 selfApprForm.comments.$invalid}">
                <div class="errorMsg">
                     <div ng-show="(selfApprForm.comments.$dirty || 
                                    selfApprForm.comments.$touched) ">
                          <div ng-show="selfApprForm.comments.$error.required">
                               If Rating is 4 to 5, employee or reviewer needs 
                               to justify with clomments.
                          </div>
                     </div>
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
         <!--Button-->
         <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit" ng- 
                      disabled="selfApprForm.$invalid">{{UiLabels.btn_submit }} 
               </button>
         </div>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert you code from

```
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="comments" 
               placeholder="Comment..." style=" height: 80px;" ng- 
               model="appList.Comments" ng-required="(appList.Rating>3) ? true : 
               false"> 
            </textarea>
```

to

```
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="comments" 
               placeholder="Comment..." style=" height: 80px;" ng- 
               model="appList.Comments" ng-required="appList.Rating>3"> 
            </textarea>
```

As angular evaluate expression **appList.Rating>3** as in true/false.

The above solution should work, assuming there is no other error is occurring somewhere in your code.